# Making my business objects implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvm-light, inotifypropertychanged

I'm trying to make my business objects implement INotifyPropertyChanged using the `Set()` method in MVVMLight. This is what I have so far:

```
public class Person : ObservableObject
{
    private readonly Entities.Person entity;

    public Person()
    {
        entity = new Entities.Person();
    }

    public int ID
    {
        get { return entity.Id; }
        set { Set(() => ID, ref entity.Id, value); }
    }
}
```

Obviously, I can't do this because I get the error:
`A property or indexer may not be passed as an out or ref parameter`

How should I do this? Do I need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged directly or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Did the accepted answer really help? Seems unlikely.

Comment: Well it's got rid of the error and my code compiles. I'd say that helps.

Comment: It's not the same code and it does not look like a replacement for what you've got.

Comment: As @HenkHolterman says, you should only mark it as accepted once you have tested and verifies it works. If only something compiling was a sign it actually worked.

Comment: @DanielKelley, it's compiling, my application is working as expected. So what else do I need to test/verify...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change:

```
Set(() => ID, ref id , value);
```

To:

```
var obj = entity.Id;
Set(() => ID, ref obj, value); 
entity.Id=obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is : `entity.Id` is a property.
you can use work around:

```
set 
{ 
int id;
Set(() => ID, ref id , value); 
entity.Id=id;
}
```

Comment: This will fail to update the controls... It has a timing issue.

Comment: Set() will raise the changed event before the entity is updated.